# Trouble understanding how pointer dereference works in C++

Tags: c++

I'm having some trouble understanding how pointer dereferencing in C++ works. Let's look at this simple example:

```
struct Value {
  int x = 0;
  
  void Inc() { x++; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Value* v = new Value();
  v->Inc();
  std::cout << v->x << std::endl; // prints 1, as I would expect

  (*v).Inc();
  std::cout << v->x << std::endl; // prints 2, but I would have expected it to print 1, 
                                  // as I  thought (*v) would create a local copy of 
                                  // the original `Value` object.

  Value v2 = *v;
  v2.Inc();
  std::cout << v->x << std::endl; // prints 2, as I would expect
```

I'm a bit confused here. I would assume that the 2nd and 3rd calls to `Inc()` would be equivalent. Namely, that `(*v).Inc()` would unfold into a temporary variable holding a copy of `v` on the stack, and that `Inc()` would then increment that copy on the stack of `v` instead of the original `v`. Why is that not the case?

Thanks

Comment: `*v` gives you a reference (technically an lvalue that refers to the value), not a copy.

Comment: Second, `std::cout << v->x << std::endl; // prints 2, as I would expect` Why do you expect `2` there?  You are printing `v->x`, which hasn't changed since the last time you printed it.

Comment: `A->B` is defined _by the standard_ as equivalent to `(*A).B`, so why would you expect different behaviors from them? As pointed out, `(*v)` is not a copy, but in fact the same object. When you assign it in `Value v2 = *v`, _then_ you have created a copy. Lastly, you incremented the copy `v2`, but then print the old value of `v`.

Comment: No, `(*v)` absolutely does not create a local copy of anything. Why would you expect that?

Answer (score 1):

`*pointer` just returns an object the `pointer` points to, quoting [[expr.unary.op]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#1):

> The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points

`Value v2 = *v` is a form of initialisation, so it actually calls a constructor. This would be equivalent to `Value v2{ *v }` (for this particular class).

---

For the part why `*pointer` doesn't create a temporary, there are well-defined rules on [when temporaries are created](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime):

> Temporary objects are created *when a prvalue is materialized so that
> it can be used as a glvalue, which occurs (since C++17)* in the
> following situations:
>
> - binding a reference to a prvalue
> - initializing an object of type
>   std::initializer_list from a braced-init-list (since C++11)
> - returning a prvalue from a function
> - conversion that creates a prvalue
>   (including T(a,b,c) and T{})
> - lambda expression (since C++11)
> - copy-initialization that requires conversion of the initializer,
> - reference-initialization to a different but convertible type or to a
>   bitfield.

plus some others scenarios for C++17. For this particular case the most important part is that indirection **returns an lvalue**, so there is no rule applicable to it if the expression doesn't partake in any other expression.

Answer (score 1):

In the `(*v).Inc();` statement, the LHS of the `.` operator is the result of the indirection of the `v` pointer. This will be an lvalue expression referring to the object to which `v` points. From [this Draft C++ Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> ##### 8.5.2.1 Unary operators      [expr.unary.op]
>
> <sup>1</sup>     The unary `*`
> operator performs *indirection*: the expression to which it is applied
> shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type
> and ***the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to
> which the expression points***.

So, in this first case, no temporary object need be created and the `Inc()` function is called on the original `Value` object created by the `new` operation.

However, in this statement: `Value v2 = *v;`, you are declaring a **separate** `Value` object and initialising it with a *copy* of the `Value` pointed to by `v`. Thus, any subsequent modifications to `v2` will not affect the object referred to by `v`.